# Not able to get control in CodedUI automation test when page get autopostback on some event

Tags: visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I am writing CodedUI automation test for my website in which i have to first select the value from combo-box on that basis the text box get visible, at that moment autopostback occur so after recording the events unable to find text box it throws error that text box not found in UI after selecting combo-box value.

```
public bool testforSearch()
        {
            #region Variable Declarations
            HtmlComboBox uIDdlDistrictsComboBox = this.UIHttpwwwsbssnaponglobWindow.UISearchYourNameEnglisDocument.UIDdlDistrictsComboBox;
            HtmlEdit uITxtEPICNoEdit = this.UIHttpwwwsbssnaponglobWindow.UISearchYourNameEnglisDocument.UITxtEPICNoEdit;
            HtmlInputButton uISearchButton = this.UIHttpwwwsbssnaponglobWindow.UISearchYourNameEnglisDocument.UISearchButton;
            #endregion

            // Go to web page 
            this.UIHttpwwwsbssnaponglobWindow.LaunchUrl(new System.Uri(this.testforSearchParams.UIHttpwwwsbssnaponglobWindowUrl));

            // Select 'Meerut' in 'ddlDistricts' combo box
            uIDdlDistrictsComboBox.SelectedItem = this.testforSearchParams.UIDdlDistrictsComboBoxSelectedItem;

            if (uITxtEPICNoEdit.WaitForControlExist())
            {
                // Type 'abcd' in 'txtEPICNo' text box
                uITxtEPICNoEdit.Text = this.testforSearchParams.UITxtEPICNoEditText;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

            // Click 'Search' button
            Mouse.Click(uISearchButton, new Point(19, 8));

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Can you be slightly more specific about how your page is working and post the UI and testing code?  Is your page posting back to render the text box after selection of the combo box?  I think you can add a WaitForControlExists call to your test after selecting the combobox item and wait for the text box to exist.

Comment: I have also called for the method you have highlighted after the value of combo-box has been set but same error has been displayed and the test case failed.

Comment: Yes, After selecting the value from combo-box the page get asynchronous post-back and than the text-box get visible . I have placed the method below is the pseudo code for the same

Comment: I think the problem is that you are creating the variables above and by the time you use them, the page is already posted and changed.  I think changing to use AlwaysSearch may help.  Or, moving them to after the selection is made.  It's hard to tell what's going on when you use the code maps so I'm not sure what is inside the methods.  Consider directly creating the scripts with help of an abstraction.  Code First, CUITe, Coded UI Fluent are all great frameworks that make it easier to see what is happening in each step.